# Is it possible to create a text file that can be read from any module?

Tags: python, module, text-files

I've found nothing in the on-line tutorials about this and I have a couple of books about python and I don't see any programs that do this so I'm thinking it might be impossible.This would be crippling to any language not to be able to share the contents of files within the the various modules in the program.

Comment: Is `open('/path/to/file')` not working?

Comment: `open('/path/to/file', 'w')`

Comment: On pretty much any platform you're going to be programming on when you create a file then it can be opened by any other code on the system (assuming that code has the correct permissions).  There might be locking and concurrency issues that make it difficult to co-ordinate reads and writes to the file happening in multiple processes at the same time. Also you may need to .flush() your writes *before* you attempt reads from other processes (or even from the same process but through other file descriptors).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Any text file you create can be accessed from any Python script/module you write (though you may run into issues with file permissions/locking/concurrency issues if you start writing more complex code).

The reason why many projects don't do this is because they either use something more sophisticated like databases, or because they want to avoid repeatedly opening and pulling data from a text file or config file -- it's typically better to read it just once, then pass that data around directly in Python. It's usually quicker and easier to manipulate that way.

In general, you'll find that any kind of input/output in programs is usually startlingly slow compared to passing/manipulating data in-memory, so usually it's good practice to try and minimize the amount of IO you do in a program.